# Convert array to object with key and value in javascript

Tags: javascript

How covert or add array elements into object.

**Now**

```
arr = [
  ["1/1/2017",113],
  ["3/11/2017",58],
  ["3/12/2017",70],
  ["3/13/2017",76]
]
```

**Should be**

```
arr = [
  {date:"1/1/2017", count:113},
  {date:"3/11/2017", count:58},
  {date:"3/12/2017", count:70},
  {date:"3/13/2017", count:76}
]
```

Comment: 1.3K rep and no effort posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr.map(function(arr1) {
 return {
  date : arr1[0],
  count : arr1[1]
 }
})
```

Comment: Or even `arr.map(([date, count]) => ({ date, count }));`

Comment: You are welcome